# ArsClassica (ClassicThesis variant) and MinionPro issue

Tags: fonts, classicthesis

[`arsclassica`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/arsclassica) provides minor modifications to the [`classicthesis`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/) package. Both provide checks in their `.sty` files for the `minionprospacing` passed to `classicthesis`. The problem is that pdflatex yields an error when `classicthesis` is loaded with `minionprospacing`, `arsclassica` is loaded after it, and any sectioning command is used:

```
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2013/../texmf-local/tex/latex/MinionPro/mt-MinionPro.cfg)
Chapter 1.

kpathsea: Running mktextfm MinionPro-Subh-osf-ot1
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation M for MinionPro-Subh-osf-ot1.
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/map/fontname/special.map?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input MinionPro-Subh-osf-ot1
This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2013)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf MinionPro-Subh-osf-ot1
! I can't find file `MinionPro-Subh-osf-ot1'.
<*> ...; nonstopmode; input MinionPro-Subh-osf-ot1
                                                  
Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...; nonstopmode; input MinionPro-Subh-osf-ot1
                                                  
Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: MinionPro-Subh-osf-ot1.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input MinionPro-Subh-osf-ot1' failed to make MinionPro-Subh-osf-ot1.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
! Font OT1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n/14.4=MinionPro-Subh-osf-ot1 at 14.4pt not loadable
: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.9 \chapter{A Chapter}
```

At first I thought there was some conflict with the sans-serif font (Iwona), but I can use `\textsf` etc. and the document is processed as long as no sectioning commands are used.

Minion Pro is installed properly as far as I can tell (I used the fonts that came with Adobe Reader and FontPro), as the document is processed successfully when no sectioning commands are used or when `arsclassica` is not loaded.

Any ideas? I hope this is not something incredibly obvious. `:-)`

## MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[minionprospacing,]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica} % Comment out to make this compile.

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A Chapter} % Comment out while arsclassica is loaded to make this work.
\textsf{Random sans-serif text.}

\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `classicthesis` loads the `MinionPro` package with the `opticals` option, but the fonts that came with Adobe Reader were only the basics (`noopticals` option: normal, bold, italics, bold italics).

This is easily fixed by passing `noopticals` as a `\documentclass` option (which will be passed on to `MinionPro`), and also replacing `\textssc` with `\textsc` in the `\spacedallcaps` and `\spacedlowsmallcaps` declarations in `arsclassica.sty`. `classicthesis` defines these two commands using `\textssc` because it uses the main font for headings – since `arsclassica` uses `iwona`, we need to replace the Minion Pro-specific `\textssc` with the generic `\textsc`.

## Output:

[image: Output]

## Solution:

### `file.tex`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,noopticals]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[minionprospacing,]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\lipsum[1]

\section{A Section}
\lipsum[2]

\subsection{A Subsection}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

### Somewhere deep in `arsclassica.sty`:

```
[...]
\ifthenelse{\boolean{@minionprospacing}}%
{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedallcaps}[1]{\sffamily%
  \textsc{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}}%
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedlowsmallcaps}[1]%
  {\sffamily\textsc{\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}%
}
[...]
```